# Gordon js can't convert .swf file to HTML5

Tags: javascript, flash

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
      <head> 
        <title>Gordon: An open source flash™ runtime written in pure JavaScript</title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/gordon.js"></script> 
      </head> 
      <body onload="new Gordon.Movie('flash.swf', {id: 'stage', width: 450, height: 300})"> 
        <div id="stage"></div> 
      </body> 
    </html>
```

i'm writing one page convert file from swf  to html 5 but it has occurred error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayList' of undefined
```

[File swf](http://f.novanet.vn/advertisements/130590497373083497_691.swf)

[Gordon js](http://gordonjs.s3.amazonaws.com/gordon.js)